# Thumb could not be created for file xxx.png

Tags: dired

Windows 10, Emacs 25.1, Dired+

I want to open image file from Emacs.
I start Emacs by `emacs -Q`

So in tutorial:

```
To enter Image-Dired, mark the image files you want to look at in the Dired buffer, using m as usual. Then type C-t d (image-dired-display-thumbs).
```

I do this steps but I get error:

```
Thumb could not be created for file d:/TEMP/test/nokia_path.png
```

Here screenshot:

[image: image_dired]

Comment: There's not enough info here to debug this, IMO. It works for me, with both vanilla Emacs (`emacs -Q`) and with Dired+. Can you create a thumbnail of that image file otherwise (without Dired)? Possibly there is some problem with that image or with the code that creates thumbnails from image files.

Comment: I success open this image by another application: XnView. Also I success open another image files by XnView.  But with Emacs any images not open. I get same error massage

Answer (score 1):

`image-dired` works using the `convert` program part of the Imagemagick toolkit.  So my crystal ball tells me you don't have that toolkit installed (or not in your `$PATH`), and for some reason there is some other `convert` executable in your `$PATH`.

Comment: Where I can get `convert` program?

Comment: As I said, it's in the Imagemagick toolkit.  On my machine I install it with `aptitude install imagemagick`.

Comment: So I must install external application `Imagemagick`. So as result the Emacs can not show image in dired mode out-of-box ?

Comment: That's right.  Emacs relies on external tools for most of its features.